# Javascript - Data Interpolation - D3 Animated Scatter

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

Trying to modify the code at the below link to create an animated scatter which shows data points moving over time.

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nations/

Struggling to wrap my head around the data interpolation section

```
// Interpolates the dataset for the given (fractional) year.
      function interpolateData(year) {
        return nations.map(function(d) {
          return {
            employee: d.employee,
            category: d.category,
            x:interpolateValues(d.x, year),
            y:interpolateValues(d.y, year)
          };
        });
      }

      // Finds (and possibly interpolates) the value for the specified year.
      function interpolateValues(values, year) {
        var i = bisect.left(values, year, 0, values.length - 1),
            a = values[i];
        if (i > 0) {
          var b = values[i - 1],
              t = (year - a[0]) / (b[0] - a[0]);
          return a[1] * (1 - t) + b[1] * t;
        }
        return a[1];
      }
    });
```

Code is expecting the data in this format, with the x and y values containing an array with the corresponding year and value.

```
d: Object
category: "1"
employee: "12017512"
x: Array[63]
y: Array[63]
```

The data I'm passing in is in this format, with a record for each each year.

```
d: Object
category: "1"
employee: "12017512"
x: 2697.3199999999993
y: 24
year: "2015"
```

How do I modify the code to accept the data in the format I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve my issue. The answer if its helps anyone was to use underscore.js and the following code.

I also found the following jsfiddle helpful.

http://jsfiddle.net/bgAzH/1/

```
  groupData = _.map(_.groupBy(data, 'dimension1', 'dimension2'), function (b) {
            return _.extend(_.pick(b[0], 'dimension1', 'dimension2'), {
                x: _.map(b, function (elem) {
                    return _.pick(elem, 'time', 'x')
                }),
                y: _.map(b, function (elem) {
                    return _.pick(elem, 'time', 'y')
                })
            });
        });
```

Then when passing the array of objects into the interpolate values functions I converted the objects to simple arrays.

`var values = values.map(function (obj) { return [Number(obj.time), obj[element]]` });